# kudan AR : Releasing memory

Tags: ios, swift, kudan

I am using the iOS Kudan AR framework which works well except a few key features are missing.

Currently when I detect a marker I am showing a ARAlphaVideoNode.  However I want to release the video / memory on a button press.

I have tried the following and the memory is still in use:

```
videoRitzNode1.visible = false
videoRitzNode1.remove()
videoRitzNode1 = nil
```

Comment: After some investigation this appears to be a bug. An internal ticket has been raised to fix this in an upcoming release.  
A slightly brute way of achieving what you want to do would be to get the instance of `ARVideoManager` and call `clearVideoTextures()`

Comment: Thanks for finding this out